# Usage of "│" (vertical bar) in Chinese?

Tags: punctuation

The Chinese wikipedia page for [vertical bars](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%B1%8E%E7%B7%9A) only talks about:

- Math
- Physics
- Computing

In the book《成都方言》I'm seeing this type of *xiehouyu* with a vertical bar in the middle of the "注":

> [image]

> 缸钵头的泥鳅儿——耍团转│滑不了

My best guess is that it meant either/or but then under the entry for 钵 it's written the same way:

> [image: bo]

> 钵 bo 钵钵，钵儿，陶盆：鸡吃一撮，狗吃一～。歇后语：“缸～头的泥鳅儿——耍团转│滑不了。”

No indications of different usage that I can see here.

What does the vertical bar do here? What does it mean? Is it either/or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it means either or.

缸～头的泥鳅儿——耍团转

缸～头的泥鳅儿——滑不了

equal to

缸～头的泥鳅儿——耍团转│滑不了

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard usage for  vertical bar │ in mandarins. So, its usage is defined by the author of the text. You can usually find the usage key from the footnote written in the early pages of a book. For example, │is used in 现代汉语词典 to separate examples. Like this:

> [蹉跎] ...... 岁月~ | 一再~

So, you can define your own usage based on your need and you might want to provide some usage note as well.